# Create Links only for Firefox

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to create a link with PHP , which can be opened only by Firefox and not by any other Browser?

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Only with Firefox</a>;
```

Because there are some Websites which works better with Firefox.

If it is possible, what i must add to the link?

THX in advance

Comment: Please don't do this. The Web is an open platform and people should be allowed to use whatever browser they have.

Comment: The only way is to serve the page based on user-agent (`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`), this can however easily be circumvented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Steve Fenton says, I do not recommend doing such things, because the web is (or should be) open. Otherwise is you still want to do it, you need to check the browser user agent of your visitor and show (or do not show) the download button.

You can acces the browser user agent easily with jQuery:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
  //Do the stuff
}
```

Or with PHP using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable.

But remember, the user can change the user agent of his/her browser.

Comment: OK i understand. I will use that only in my LAN. 
THX very much

Answer (score 1):

You can Detect Browser by Jquery and you can show or hide a tag.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

which gives current browser.